# Comparing securestring from inputfield with database in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

XMAL

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="*" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged" Background="#545d6a" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"/>
```

Code behind

```
private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DataContext != null)
        { ((dynamic)this.DataContext).SecurePassword = ((PasswordBox)sender).SecurePassword; }
    }
```

I have a class Klant with a property Paswoord that i want to compare with the secureString.

ViewModel

```
public SecureString SecurePassword { private get; set; }

Klant = DataBaseOperations.OphalenKlantViaUsername(UserName);
            if (Klant != null)
            {
                if (Klant.Paswoord == SecurePassword.ToString())
                {
                    the password is correct and the program continues
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("the password is incorrect");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                User does not exist.
            }
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What error/problem are you getting?

Comment: I get back my messagebox.show("the password is incorrect");  I know this probably goes against all the rules of security but it's for a school project. We haven't learned this yet, but I just want my program to work and move on. So if you could help me with a simple solution, that would be nice :)

Comment: I like that you are not trying to bind the password! This is not recommended and would make the PasswordBox redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently comparing equality of the password with the string *representation* of the `SecureString` class. `SecureString.ToString` will not return the secured password as string. You will have to explicitly convert it:

```
private bool IsPasswordValid(SecureString referencePassword, SecureString password)
{
  IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
  try
  {
    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
    string plainTextPassword = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);

    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(referencePassword);
    string plainTextReferencePassword = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);

    return plainTextReferencePassword.Equals(plainTextPassword, StringComparison.Ordinal);
  } 
  finally 
  {
    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
if (IsPasswordValid(Klant.Paswoord, this.SecurePassword)
{
  // Password is valid
}
```

Comment: hey when I debug it I see that it indeed returns the password I just entered but the password that is in the database is still a System.Security.SecureString. Any idea how to fix this? :)

Comment: Do you mean `Klant.Paswoord` returns a `SecureString`? _"I see that it indeed returns the password I just entered"_: what is _it_?

Comment: yes, klant.Paswoord returns a SecureString indeed. And when i debug, i see that its stille encrypted

Comment: This wasn't clear from your question. I have updated the answer. Try it. How do you persist the SecureString, as blob?

Comment: It's better to encrypt and store the password using a hashing algorithm like [SHA256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netcore-3.1). You let the user create a password and store the hashed password in the database. Then, when the user enters his password to sign in, you hash the input  and compare it to the hash code version from the database. Don't compare plain strings. Compare their hashed value. This is more safe. Storing SecureString is not safe.

Comment: SecureString is just meant to prevent the password/user input from being created as string in memory. It's not encrypted. You can steal the SecureString from the database and convert it to a string, simply by using the above method. But it's not easy to decrypt a hash code generated by hashing algorithms like SHA512 or others. Depending on the algorithm it will be impossible to decrypt a hash code in reasonable time. Mind that SHA256 or SHA512 are not considered really safe. You can and should improve them by adding a salt to the password. See PBKDF2 or bcrypt for better algorithms.